# How can I use one-hot encoded labels with some sklearn classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a multiclass classification task with 10 classes. As such, I used sklearn's [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to transform the one-column labels to 10-columns labels. I was trying to fit the training data. Although I was able to do this with [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), I got the below error message when fitting with [GaussianNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html):

```
ValueError: bad input shape (1203L, 10L)
```

I understand the allowed shape of y in these two classifiers is different:

GaussianNB:

```
y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
```

RandomForest:

```
y : array-like, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]
```

The question is, why is this? Wouldn't this be contradictory to ["All classifiers in scikit-learn do multiclass classification out-of-the-box"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)? Any way to go around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is, why is this?

It is because of a slight missunderstanding, in scikit-learn you **do not** encode labels, you pass it as one dimensional vector of labels, thus instead of

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

you literally pass

```
1 2 3
```

So why does random forest accepts a different scheme? Because it **is not** for multiclass setting! It is for **multi label** where each instance can have many labels, like

```
1 1 0
1 1 1
0 0 0
```

> Wouldn't this be contradictory to "All classifiers in scikit-learn do multiclass classification out-of-the-box"?

Contrary - it is the easiest solution - to never ask for one-hot unless it is multi-label,

> Any way to go around it?

Yup, just do not encode - pass raw labels :-)

Comment: Great. Thank you for the clarification!